# Error "ALPN is not configured properly" when using firebase Admin SDK and netty in same project

Tags: java, maven, firebase, netty, firebase-admin

when im having firebase and netty in same java maven project im getting this error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ALPN is not configured properly

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the minimal code in the project that reproduces the error?

Comment: Firebase already depends on [Netty](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/pom.xml#L62). Make sure you're using a version that is compatible.